# Kernel data structure that shows which CPUs are partitioned (isolated) using tuned?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-parameters, tuned

This is for Red Hat Linux 7.9, kernel 3.10.0-1160.71.1 .

I would like to know what kernel data structure can be used to show which CPUs it thinks are isolated using tuned. This means I've isolated CPUs not by using the `isolcpus` kernel command line parameter but rather using `tuned-adm profile cpu-partitioning`. Is there any such visible data structure?

Note: I'm not looking to `cat /etc/tuned/cpu-partitioning-variables.conf`, or even to `tr ' ' '\n' < /proc/cmdline | grep tuned.non_isolcpus`. Obviously, I can do that.

Why not review `tuned.non_isolcpus`? Perhaps I can illustrate with an example: In `/etc/tuned/cpu-partitioning-variables.conf` you can set the `no_balanace_cores` on a system. After reboot, you can `cat /run/tuned/no-balance-cpus.txt` and review your setting. However, you can also for example

```
# grep . /proc/sys/kernel/sched_domain/cpu15/domain*/flags
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_domain/cpu15/domain0/flags:4655
/proc/sys/kernel/sched_domain/cpu15/domain1/flags:25647
```

and if you review https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/include/linux/sched.h#L769 and https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.10/source/kernel/sched/core.c, you can see that  `SD_LOAD_BALANCE` is `0x0001`. Since the numbers above are odd, in my case, I will not have load balancing on CPU 15. This is a reflection of the CPU's actual settings, not simply an indicator of what the system thinks it told the kernel to do.

Is there a data structure in /proc or /sys which contains similar information but about CPU isolation?  Specifically as it pertains to tuned?

I've spent a few hours scouring /proc, /sys, and Google to no avail. Thanks.